# TwoWay Data Binding Combobox with BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

OK, so here's my dilema. I have a windows form which will be used to maintain an SQL Table. The SQL Table has foreign keys pointing to Code Tables. I'm using a BindingNavigator and a BindingSource to display the contents of this table one row at a time in the form using textboxes, comboboxes and datepickers. The form displays the table's key field, the BindingNavigator, and one of the main table's fields called "Brief Description" in a groupbox at the top of the screen. The purpose of this group is to allow the user to key in an ID number, or pick an item from the combobox to view/edit. (Unable to post images as I'm a new user).
I have managed to get the data displayed on the form to change according to the BindingNavigator's navigation, i.e. back, fwd, etc., But I can't get the form to display the appropriate data when selecting an item from the Brief Description combobox. This must be something to do with the binding of my controls. Possibly that I only have a Oneway binding with the BindingSource and not a TwoWay binding, but I can't figure out how to make it a TwoWay binding.

Here is the code that sets up the form which run in the FormLoad event:

```
private void SoftwareRequestMaint_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Open connection
        conn.Open();
        //string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Requests; SELECT * FROM Priority; SELECT * FROM Category;" + 
        //    " SELECT * FROM Users; SELECT * FROM System";
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Requests ORDER BY BriefDesc; " +
            "SELECT combined = Description + ' [' + convert(varchar,Priority_ID) + ']', Priority_ID  FROM Priority ORDER BY combined; " +
            "SELECT combined = Description + ' [' + convert(varchar,Category_ID) + ']', Category_ID FROM Category ORDER BY combined; " +
            "SELECT combined = Givname + ' ' + Surname, User_ID FROM Users ORDER BY combined; " + 
            "SELECT combined = Description + ' [' + convert(varchar,System_ID) + ']', System_ID FROM System ORDER BY combined";
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

        //due to mulitple SELECTs, set up table mappings other wise need to use Table, Table1, Table2 etc...
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Requests");
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Priority");
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Category");
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table3", "Users");
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table4", "System");

        //Go get the data
        da.Fill(ds);

        //Set relationships
        DataColumn colParent =
            ds.Tables["Requests"].Columns["Priority"];
        DataColumn colChild =
             ds.Tables["Priority"].Columns["Priority_ID"];
        DataRelation RequestsPriority =
             new DataRelation("RequestsPriority", colParent, colChild, false);
        ds.Relations.Add(RequestsPriority);

        //Bind the dataset to the binding source
        bsRequests.DataSource = ds.Tables["Requests"];
        bsRequests.Binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        //Bind the Textbox's Text property to the Bindingsource's Requests_ID column
        uxIDTxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsRequests, "Requests_ID");
        uxMenuOptTxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsRequests, "MenuOpt");
        uxProcessNameTxt.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsRequests, "ProcessName");

        //Set up data sources for combos
        uxBriefDescCbo.DataSource = bsRequests; // ds.Tables["Requests"]; //which one is correct?
        uxBriefDescCbo.DisplayMember = "BriefDesc";
        uxBriefDescCbo.ValueMember = "Requests_ID";
        uxBriefDescCbo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsRequests, "Requests_ID");


        uxSystemCbo.DataSource = ds.Tables["System"];   //the source of the data for this cbo
        uxSystemCbo.DisplayMember = "combined";         //the column name of the table to display
        uxSystemCbo.ValueMember = "System_ID";          //the id for that item/record
        uxSystemCbo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsRequests, "System"); //Bind the cbo to the Navigator's data source, i.e. the binding source

        uxPriorityCbo.DataSource = ds.Tables["Priority"];
        uxPriorityCbo.DisplayMember = "combined";
        uxPriorityCbo.ValueMember = "Priority_ID";
        uxPriorityCbo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsRequests, "Priority");

        uxCategoryCbo.DataSource = ds.Tables["Category"];
        uxCategoryCbo.DisplayMember = "combined";
        uxCategoryCbo.ValueMember = "Category_ID";
        uxCategoryCbo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsRequests, "Category");

        uxRequestedByCbo.DataSource = ds.Tables["Users"];
        uxRequestedByCbo.DisplayMember = "combined";
        uxRequestedByCbo.ValueMember = "User_ID";
        uxRequestedByCbo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsRequests, "RequestedBy");

        uxAssignedToCbo.DataSource = ds.Tables["Users"];
        uxAssignedToCbo.DisplayMember = "combined";
        uxAssignedToCbo.ValueMember = "User_ID";
        uxAssignedToCbo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsRequests, "AssignedTo");

        uxSignedOffByCbo.DataSource = ds.Tables["Users"];
        uxSignedOffByCbo.DisplayMember = "combined";
        uxSignedOffByCbo.ValueMember = "User_ID";
        uxSignedOffByCbo.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsRequests, "SignedOffBy");

        //Bind text boxes to combos
        uxRequestDetailsRtb.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsRequests, "Details");
        uxItemsChangedRtb.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsRequests, "ItemsChanged");
        uxInstallationInstructionsRtb.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsRequests, "InstallInstr");
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        SAPSCommon.Instance.ShowErrorMsg(excp.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
    }

    //Reset dirty data flag after populating controls
    dirtyData = false;
}
```

BTW The comboboxes are unsorted, i.e. their Sorted property is set to "False". The sorting is done as part of the SQL SELECT statements.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Regards,
Walter